# Spring Dependency Injection with TestNG

Tags: junit, spring, testng

Spring support JUnit quite well on that:
With the `RunWith` and `ContextConfiguration` annotation, things look very intuitive

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:dao-context.xml")
```

This test will be able to run both in Eclipse & Maven in correctly.
I wonder if there is similar stuff for TestNG. I'm considering moving to this "Next Generation" Framework but I didn't find a match for testing with Spring.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

It works with TestNG as well. Your *test* class needs to ***extend*** one of the following classes:

- [`org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/test/context/testng/AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.html)
- [`org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/test/context/testng/AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests.html)

Comment: What a mess. Firstly enforces specific class hierarchy. Secondly is quite confusing as test case that uses `@Transactional` can extends non-transactional version by mistake. But unfortunately there is no other way to use a Spring with TestNG.

Comment: @GrzesiekD. My hope is that something may have changed in 4.5 years. :) So please recheck the status quo.

Comment: first don't work for me, but second is ok. so what's the difference with and without transactional ?

Answer (score 33):

Here is an example that worked for me:

```
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Test
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
public class TestValidation extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    public void testNullParamValidation() {
        // Testing code goes here!
    }
}
```

Comment: @Test annotation for class? :o

Answer (score 25):

Spring and TestNG work well together, but there are some things to be aware of. Aside from subclassing `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests`, you need to be aware of how it interacts with standard TestNG setup/teardown annotations.

TestNG has four levels of setup

- BeforeSuite
- BeforeTest
- BeforeClass
- BeforeMethod

which occur exactly as you would expect (great example of self-documenting APIs). These all have an optional value called `dependsOnMethods` which can take a String or String[], which is the name or name(s) of the methods at the same level.

The `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` class has a `BeforeClass` annotated method called `springTestContextPrepareTestInstance`, which you must set your setup method to depend on if you are using an autowired class in it. For methods, you don't have to worry about the autowiring, since it occurs when the test class is setup in that before class method.

This just leaves the question of how you might use an autowired class in a method annotated with `BeforeSuite`. You can do this by manually calling `springTestContextPrepareTestInstance` - while its not setup by default to do this, I've done it several times successfully.

So, to illustrate, a modified version of Arup's example:

```
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Test
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
public class TestValidation extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    private IAutowiredService autowiredService;

    @BeforeClass(dependsOnMethods={"springTestContextPrepareTestInstance"})
    public void setupParamValidation(){
        // Test class setup code with autowired classes goes here
    }

    @Test
    public void testNullParamValidation() {
        // Testing code goes here!
    }
}
```

Comment: The method org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests#springTestContextPrepareTestInstance already has the annotation @BeforeClass so this solution appear to me as redundant.

Comment: This solution allows you to add autowire-field dependent code to your test. "springTestContextPrepareTestInstance" being a "before class" method doesn't guarantee that it will run before the "before class" of a sub-class - you need to explicitly set the dependsOnMethods field

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me.  By default, the `@Autowire` seems to take place VERY late, after @BeforeTest (but before @Test). I tried adding the dependsOnMethods, but then I get: MyClass is depending on method protected void org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance() throws java.lang.Exception, which is not annotated with @Test...

Comment: Edit: just found a solution (problem was BeforeSuite doesn't work with this).  Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192562/spring-autowiring-happens-after-beforeclass-when-running-test-with-maven-surefi

Comment: What if i want to access beans in Listener? It seems if you add @Listener, it gets initialized before the AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests methods are called