# No runnable methods with testNG

Tags: java, junit, testng

I am writing integration tests with TestNG and facing this trivial issue.

```
No runnable methods
     java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
```

Test class is like this (After Stephen's suggestion, I removed SpringJunitRunner):

```
@Test
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:spring-configuration/mobiusdatabase-integration-testing.xml" })
public class PersistUrlTests extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

        @Autowired
        protected MobiusDatabaseServiceClient mobiusDatabaseServiceClient;

        @Autowired
        UrlDAO urlDAO;

        @Autowired
        ScraperUrlDAO scraperUrlDAO;

        @BeforeClass
        public static void init() throws Exception {

        }

        @Test
        public void checkTest() {
            GetActiveCategoriesResponse response = mobiusDatabaseServiceClient.newGetActiveCategoriesCall().call();
            System.out.println(response.getCategoryList());
            Assert.assertTrue(true);
        }
}
```

This error usually occurs when we don't have `@Test` annotation or if we don't have `@Runner`. Do we need some other set-up for `TestNG`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` to run a TestNG unit test.  That won't work.  A `JUnit` runner expects to find test classes designated by a *different* `@Test` annotation.

I don't know what the correct solution is though, because there isn't a `SpringTestNGClassRunner` class in the obvious package.

**UPDATE** - here's the explanation!

- [Does TestNG has runner like SpringJUnit4ClassRunner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624724/does-testng-has-runner-like-springjunit4classrunner)
- [Spring Dependency Injection with TestNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608528/spring-dependency-injection-with-testng)

Comment: Hi Stephen, I tried using suggested abstract class but it still throws the same error. Modified the question with new set-up.

Comment: I can't diagnose that without a *full* stacktrace