# How to test service class with @Autowired

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit, spring-test-mvc

I have a service class `MyService` which is defined and being used in controller like so:

```
public interface MyService {
  public String someMethod() 
}

@Service("myService")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
  public String someMethod() {
    return "something";
  }
}

@Controller 
public class MyController {
  @Autowired
  public MyService myService;

  @RequestMapping(value="/someurl", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public String blah () {
    return myService.getsomeMethod();
  }
}
```

I'd like to write a test case for the `someMethod` method, however, the following doesn't work. How can I wire in the implementation class?

```
public class MyServiceImplTest {
 @Autowired
 private MyService myService;

 @Test
 public void testSomeMethod() {
   assertEquals("something", myService.someMethod());
 }
```

}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092322/spring-testng-integration-tests-injecting-dao-with-annotations-fails/13093822#13093822

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MyServiceImplTest {
    private MyService myService = new MyServiceImpl();

    @Test
    public void testSomeMethod() {
        assertEquals("something", myService.someMethod());
    }
}
```

Why inject the bean in your test rather than creating an instance by yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
 // specifies the Spring configuration to load for this test fixture
@ContextConfiguration("yourapplication-config.xml")
```

Also see [the Spring.IO docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#testcontext-support-classes) for more detail.