# How to substitute JUnit in Spring Boot with TestNG for more robust testing purpose

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, testng, spring-test

Recently, while running some tests, I wanted to use TestNG instead of JUnit.

however when I added the dependency to pom file, imported the jar files.
imported annotation, when I ran it, it passes for JUnit, but it's failing for TestNG with NPE (NullPointerException)

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext.getBean(java.lang.Class)" because "this.context" is null

can someone show me the way to fix this issue?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have done the correct injection. Refer to the below answer -

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2608580/14899650

Comment: Thank you @Satyam, I looked at the post, it makes lots of sense. It seems like a workaround that still works. hope Spring will update to TestNG one day :)